# This bus is for the use of US residents only or This bus is for the use of the US residents only?

Tags: definite-article

> This bus is for the use of US residents only

or

> This bus is for the use of **the** US residents only?

Should I add a `the` before `US` in this sentence?

Comment: Why? Usually it is better to omit unnecessary words without reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would only say *the US residents* if there were one or more different groups of people--in that place that might get on the bus if they didn't know--and you had to be specific about which group.

If the statement isn't directed toward any existing group but anyone wanting to get on the bus, *the* should be omitted.